# Pandas cumsum using large amounts of memory

Tags: python, memory, pandas

I'm using cumsum in pandas to create a running count and it's using up more memory than the dataframe itself takes up. The function I'm running is as follows:

```
def gen_obs_num(df):
    df.sort(columns=['Index', 'Date'], inplace=True)
    df['obs_num'] = 1
    df['obs_num'] = df.groupby(['Index', 'Date'])['obs_num'].cumsum()
    return df
```

Any idea on how to perform the same operation in a more memory efficient manner?

Basically I want to add a column to a dataframe of the following format:

```
Index       Date
  A       1/1/2000
  A       1/2/2000
  A       1/2/2000
  B       1/1/2000
  B       1/1/2000
  B       1/10/2000
```

So that it becomes:

```
Index       Date      obs_num
  A       1/1/2000      1
  A       1/2/2000      1
  A       1/2/2000      2
  B       1/1/2000      1
  B       1/1/2000      2
  B       1/10/2000     1
```

Comment: What size is your DataFrame (rows x cols), and what dtype is `Date`? If it's `object` convert it to a datetime with `pd.to_datetime` or `df.convert_objects`.

Comment: If you're working with a recent version, you could try `df.groupby(["Index", "Date"]).cumcount() + 1` to see how that behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSM's answer dramatically reduced memory usage. To reiterate, the best approach is to use cumcount() instead:

```
df['obs_num'] = df.groupby(["Index", "Date"]).cumcount() + 1
```